# Automate Excel workbook in SharePoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint-2010, infopath

I have a project in which there are Excel workbooks. All the workbooks have the same lay-out. The only difference is the information in it (from different projects). The workbook contains some calculations, charts, etc. The client doesn't want a user to be able to copy the workbook. He wants something like a form in which the information can be submitted (professional look). I tried different things, like create an InfoPath form for user input, connected it via Excel Web Services to put the values in the workbook and get the chart (because the chart uses different cells, so I couldn't use web chart part). But the problem with this approach is that the values entered in the form are saved, but not the chart. The chart is the main object of the workbook (it's all about it). I don't know if I'm doing it right or not. Is it possible to achieve what I described in the same course?

Can I get some directives?